# Disable complete log trace for Mobile application in Rhomobile

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I referred to the Rhomobile documentation it mentions

## log level

0-trace, 1-info(app level), 3-warnings, 4-errors

I want to disable log trace completely for production. Which level should I set it to?

Answer (score 1):

For production, as wrote in the comments in rhoconfig.txt, the suggestion is to put it a level 3 (errors), there's no level 4:

```
# Rhodes log properties
# log level
# 0-trace, 1-info(app level), 2-warnings, 3-errors
# for production set to 3
```

Comment: Just saw that in the documentations the **MinSeverity** is reported wrongly, I've reported the issue on the [documentation repository on github](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhomobile-docs/issues/253)